# Adding types to a const in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have this variable declaration, I wish to add type string to typecheck that these variables are string objects

How would I go about doing this

```
const { someID, someName, someAPIenvironment } = useParams();
```

Here is what I tried

```
const {(someID:string), (someName:string), (someAPIenvironment:string)} = useParams();
```

Am I correct with my implementation?

Comment: No need to type those states. states returned are already typed inside useParams() custom hook.

Answer (score 1):

If `useParams` doesn't have a useful type signature, you can cast it to your own.

```
interface IParams {
    someID: string,
    someName: string,
    someAPIenvironment: string
}

const { someID, someName, someAPIenvironment } = useParams() as IParams;
```

Note: this gives you no type-safety as this won't perform any type checking at run-time. If you want to be sure they are strings, you will need to use `typeof()`, eg.

```
typeof(someID) === 'string' && typeof(someName) === 'string' && typeof(someAPIenvironment) === 'string'
```

There are also some useful schema validation libraries out there, such as [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup), where you can compare objects to a pre-defined schema.